# Automatically select multiple options in the second dropdown based on the options selected in the first dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have two dropdownlists. In both you can select multiple options.

Figure 1: Two dropdownlists

[image]

Figure 2: Code for the dropdownlists

[image]

As you will see I placed the dropdown for devices in a partial view. The code
for this you can see in figure 3.

Figure 3: Partial view for device dropdown

[image]

The idea behind this partial view is that when options are selected on the first dropdown, the whole dropdown will be refreshed by replacing the partial view with the dropdown in it.

Figure 4: Ajax method

[image]

This ajax method will call the action method in the controller which you will see in figure 5 when there is a change event on the first dropdown. It will pass the values selected to the action method.

Figure 5: Action method in the controller

[image]

The only problem now is that i get a 'object' as type instead of string[] in my action method. How can I get these values out of this object? I also tried to do it with an ajax POST, but then the partial view would not refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand very well your problem, i dont get the sense of get the same list you´re sending.

But if you are declaring the model in the Action DevicesDDL as a DeviceDDLViewModel and returning to the PartialView as an object, so you will have and...object. Maybe if you change this line

```
return PartialView(model);
```

For this

```
return PartialViewModel(model.ActiveDevices);
```

That will return a list...the same list you´re sending :/

Comment: Indeed the same list is send, but the key difference is that certain options are now selected (which they weren't in the first place) based on the options chosen in the first dropdown.